# spring-boot creates logging.path_IS_UNDEFINED.log file

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

my spring-boot application creates a log file with name `logging.path_IS_UNDEFINEDlogging.file_IS_UNDEFINED.log` which clearly states that `logging.path` and `logging.file` properties are not set while logback is initializing log configuration. This sounds like a duplicate of this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251983/springboot-with-logback-creating-log-path-is-undefined-folder) However, I tried all the suggested solutions from that post. I am using spring-boot version 2.0

**application-dev.yaml**

```
spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  application:
    name: my-application

logging:
  path: /var/logs/${spring.application.name}/
  file:
    max-size: 10MB
    max-history: 5
```

**spring-logback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml"/>

    <property name="logging.pattern.console" value="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %X{transactionId} %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    <property name="logging.file.roll-pattern" value="application-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log"/>

    <springProfile name="dev">
        <property resource="application-dev.yaml" />
        <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>
        <logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO"/>
        <logger name="com.myapp" level="DEBUG"/>

        <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>${logging.path}${logging.file}.log</file>
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <!-- daily rollover -->
                <fileNamePattern>${logging.path}${logging.file}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>

                <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history capped at 3GB total size -->
                <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
                <totalSizeCap>3GB</totalSizeCap>

            </rollingPolicy>

            <encoder>
                <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>

        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
            <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        </root>
    </springProfile>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: For googlers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322709/unable-to-use-spring-property-placeholders-in-logback-xml/29323582

Answer (score 2):

Altenratively, you can set a "path" variable in your logback.xml and append to it your filename to store it in another "LOG_FILE" property :

```
    <springProperty scope="context" name="path" 
    source="logging.path" />
<property name="LOG_FILE" 
    value="${path}/myapp.log" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Happy new year everybody! So, I came up with a similar issue when I've updated the **spring boot version (2.4.1)** and I started getting the LOG_PATH_IS_UNDEFINED error.

I did a bit of research and I'm guessing there is a problem with the mapping of the properties from logging.path to LOG_PATH. (I manually debugged the logger and the properties were being load)

My solution/Patch:

I added a manual mapping to the logback-spring.xml at the very top:

`<springProperty scope="context" name="LOG_PATH" source="logging.path"/>`

Now it is working for me...

Answer (score 1):

logging.path you initialized in **application-dev.yaml** set variable *${LOG_PATH}* in **spring-logback.xml**.

if you initialize variable *logging.file*, you can use variable *${LOG_FILE}* in **spring-logback.xml**
so you should initialize like below.

```
logging:
    file: /var/logs/myApp.log
```

and set variable in **spring-logback.xml**

```
<property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE}"/>
<file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
```