# logback failed to rename context [varname_IS_UNDEFINED] as [myproject]

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

`springboot 2.1.3`

I set logback-spring.xml,

```xml
<springProperty scope="context" name="logPath", source="myapp.log.path" defaultValue="/home/logs/myappLog"></springProperty>
<springProperty scope="context" name="varname", source="spring.application.name" defaultValue="abc"></springProperty>

<contextName>${varname}</contextName>
```

application.properties

```
spring.application.name=myproject
```

I got error

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected:
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ContextNameAction - Failed to rename context [abc] as [myproject] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context has been already given a name
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:169)
...
...
```

I search some articles, [springboot-with-logback-creating-log-path-is-undefined-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251983/springboot-with-logback-creating-log-path-is-undefined-folder), [LOG_FILE_IS_UNDEFINED log file is being created in boot 1.4.5](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8675), but I did not fine the solution.